# How to deal with Reads[Future[A]]

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using PlayFramework and the json lib.

I have a quite common use case for the deserialization : I need to check the existence of an id in a DB.

Anyone use `Reads[Future[T]]` or it's a bad idea ?

Seems I need to convert `Future[JsResult[T]]` into `JsResult[Future[T]]` to play with existing combinator …

Example of code that I want

```
  def existenceReads[A](otherwise : ValidationError)(f: String => Future[Option[A]]) : Reads[Future[A]] = 
  Reads[Future[A]](js => StringReads.reads(js).flatMap {
    v => f(v).map(_.fold(JsError(otherwise))(a => JsSuccess(a)))
  })
```

Do you know if there is sample of code doing that kind of tricks ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to couple JSON deserializing with database checking like this? Wouldn't it be easier to test and reason about (i.e. separate stages and/or error messages) if you first deserialized your JSON to an object, *then* checked whether it could be found?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether I understood your question correctly, but it is ok to work with futures in play.

You can define your action as `Action.async`, and now it expects `Future[Result]`. You can have your future mapped into a proper result and return such future.

Example:

```
def checkId = Action.async {
 val jsResult = existenceReads(...)
 jsResult map {
   case JsError(error) => BadRequest
   case JsSuccess(val) => Ok
 }
}
```

The type `JsResult[Future[T]]` sounds weird. If you have some operation that produces `JsResult`, you would expect it to be async if you already work with futures